# How to adjust cursor size in Ubuntu/Chromium?

Tags: chromium, cursor, resize

How to adjust cursor size in the Ubuntu/Chromium?  I have installed this on an aging Acer One netbook.  I had replaced the original Windows XP with Ubuntu 14 but due to the size of this little netbook.. it was sluggish and overkill for the limited intended usage requirements.  Thus, Chromium was installed which is just about perfect for a netbook.  I am disabled and the present cursor is really small and hard to place.

Comment: Which Ubuntu 14? 14.04 or 14.10?

Comment: On Unity, if you `apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` I *believe* you can change the cursor size.

Comment: You could also add the Greasemonkey extension to Chrom(ium|e) and write a small userscript that injects a bit of CSS that enlarges the cursor on every page you visit.